# Identify Django queryset from SQL logs

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, logging, django-queryset

I use Django 1.8.17 (I know it's not so young anymore).
I have logged slow requests on PostGres for more than one minute.

I have a lot of trouble finding the Queryset to which the SQL query listed in the logs belongs.

Is there an identifier that could be added to the Queryset to find the associated SQL query in the Logs or a trick to easily identify it?

Here is an exemple of common Queryset almost impossible to identify as I have several similars ones.

```
Queryset:
Video.objects.filter(status='online').order_by('created')

LOGs:
duration: 1056.540 ms  statement: SELECT "video"."id", "video"."title", 
"video"."description", "video"."duration", "video"."html_description", 
"video"."niche_id", "video"."owner_id", "video"."views", 
"video"."rating" FROM "video" WHERE "video"."status" = 'online' 
ORDER BY "video"."created"

Desired LOGs:
duration: 1056.540 ms  statement: SELECT "video"."id", "video"."title", 
"video"."description", "video"."duration", "video"."html_description", 
"video"."niche_id", "video"."owner_id", "video"."views", 
"video"."rating" FROM "video" WHERE "video"."status" = 'online' 
ORDER BY "video"."created" (ID=555)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, the example above shows the queryset belonging to the log. What do you mean by 'identify the queryset'?

Comment: I know it's the other way round, but if you print the `query` of a queryset (e.g. as debug logging) for all your suspicious query sets, you should be able to match them.

Comment: @dirkgroten this is an example. In fact I don't know which Queryset it is. I'm just showing how basic Querysets can be and hard to associate with SQL LOGs

Comment: @dirkgroten . Print the query is about to put print on a lot of Querysets. Add print after each of them, then remove it, it is a hard task. I wonder how it is made usually. I will end with this if I don't find any parameter to achieve my goals but I'm think sure somebody though about this before me.

Comment: In development you can use the Django-debug-toolbar which will show all your SQL queries and the line of code that triggered it.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have DJTB installed but It is not very handy, I have to scroll all pages and check for the right SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197821/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-kollo).

Answer (score 0):

Add middleware to log a warning when a query takes a long time:

```
class LongQueryLogMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        for q in connection.queries:
            if float(q['time']) >= settings.LONG_QUERY_TIME_SEC:
                logger.warning("Found long query (%s sec): %s", q['time'], q['sql'])
        return response
```

I've made a small [gist](https://gist.github.com/deegeenl/f4238634f67b65256c878cfe75d8557e.js) with all the code. Sorry for the indentation, GitHub keeps removing the indentation.

In the code above I only log the query, but you can add `request` information that will help you identify where the query comes from.

Comment: This logs the SQL that I already have on my Postgresl Logs using the log_min_duration_statement . What I need is to "mark" the SQL queries in the Queryset to identify which Queryset is corresponding to the SQL logs. And btw this middleware is not working on Django 1.8, it is the new MiddleWare scheme, I had to adapt it.

Comment: But if you also add request information to the log message you’ll know where the queryset was triggered, E.g. in which view. That then makes it easy to figure out in your code which queryset it was.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Django, so I may be off the mark, but there's a simple trick I heard from one of the people that runs RDS:

Add an identifier to your query as a comment.

So, include a UUID, ID, label, etc. to the query

-- as a comment

and that will flow through to the log. This is an easy way to tie Postgres log entries to specific methods/scripts, it sounds like it would need a bit of adaptation to be useful in your case. (If the idea applies at all.)

Comment: That is the point! But sadly Django doesn't support comments. I think it will not be implemented as it may not be the solution.